# Finding statistics after grouping in data.table

Tags: r, data.table

I had a small question in regards to data.table. Since i'm not so good at it i'm not quite sure how I can do this in data.table.

Basically I have 3 columns and want to group by the first two columns ( key and date ) and then for each key and each date, find the maximum and minimum that occurred in the third column ( fare)

I tried doing this but it gives me an error

```
flights[, c("max_day", "min_day") := unlist(lapply(gross_fare, findr)), by = c("key", "created_date")]
```

```
Error in `[.data.table`(flights, , `:=`(c("max_day", "min_day"), unlist(lapply(gross_fare,  : 
  Supplied 18 items to be assigned to group 1 of size 9 in column 'max_day'. The RHS length must either be 1 (single values are ok) or match the LHS length exactly. If you wish to 'recycle' the RHS please use rep() explicitly to make this intent clear to readers of your code.
```

findr is a function which just finds the max and min i.e.

```
findr <- function(x) {list(max = max(x), min = min(x)}
```

I've done what I want to do in dplyr and I'll attach the code for that, but since i have millions of rows, dplyr eats up my ram so data.table would help

```
test <- flights %>%
  select(key, created_date, gross_fare) %>%
  group_by(key, created_date) %>%
  summarise(
            max_day = max(gross_fare),
            min_day = min(gross_fare),
            diff = max_day - min_day) %>%
  arrange(created_date)
```

I've put the dput output if anyone wants to use that
If anyone can help that'd be great, thank you :)

```
data.table::setDT(structure(list(key = c("LHE_KHI_LHE+KHI_PA-405_15.0_1", "KHI_ISB_KHI+ISB_PK-370_20.0_0", 
"LHE_KHI_LHE+KHI_PK-307_20.0_0", "ISB_KHI_ISB+KHI_PF-124_20.0_1", 
"LHE_KHI_LHE+KHI_PK-307_20.0_0", "LHE_KHI_LHE+KHI_PA-405_15.0_1", 
"KHI_LHE_KHI+LHE_PK-304_20.0_0", "KHI_ISB_KHI+ISB_PA-204_15.0_1", 
"ISB_KHI_ISB+KHI_PA-207_15.0_1", "KHI_ISB_KHI+ISB_PA-200_20.0_1", 
"KHI_LHE_KHI+LHE_PK-304_40.0_0", "ISB_KHI_ISB+KHI_PA-201_35.0_1", 
"ISB_KHI_ISB+KHI_ER-501_20.0_1", "KHI_LHE_KHI+LHE_PF-145_20.0_2", 
"KHI_ISB_KHI+ISB_PA-204_20.0_1", "LHE_KHI_LHE+KHI_PA-401_0.0_0", 
"ISB_KHI_ISB+KHI_PK-309_40.0_0", "KHI_ISB_KHI+ISB_PF-123_20.0_2", 
"ISB_KHI_ISB+KHI_PA-205_15.0_1", "LHE_KHI_LHE+KHI_PF-142_0.0_0", 
"ISB_KHI_ISB+KHI_PA-223_15.0_1", "ISB_KHI_ISB+KHI_PF-126_20.0_2", 
"ISB_KHI_ISB+KHI_PK-309_20.0_0", "KHI_ISB_KHI+ISB_PF-121_20.0_2", 
"ISB_KHI_ISB+KHI_PK-373_20.0_0", "KHI_LHE_KHI+LHE_PF-145_20.0_2", 
"KHI_LHE_KHI+LHE_PA-402_15.0_1", "LHE_KHI_LHE+KHI_PA-407_20.0_1", 
"KHI_ISB_KHI+ISB_PK-308_40.0_0", "KHI_LHE_KHI+LHE_PF-145_20.0_2", 
"LHE_KHI_LHE+KHI_PF-144_0.0_0", "ISB_KHI_ISB+KHI_PK-369_40.0_0", 
"ISB_KHI_ISB+KHI_PF-124_20.0_2", "KHI_ISB_KHI+ISB_PA-204_15.0_1", 
"KHI_ISB_KHI+ISB_PA-200_15.0_1", "ISB_KHI_ISB+KHI_PF-124_20.0_1", 
"KHI_ISB_KHI+ISB_PK-300_20.0_0", "ISB_KHI_ISB+KHI_PF-122_20.0_2", 
"KHI_ISB_KHI+ISB_PK-368_20.0_0", "KHI_ISB_KHI+ISB_PA-204_15.0_1", 
"ISB_KHI_ISB+KHI_ER-503_20.0_1", "ISB_KHI_ISB+KHI_PA-209_15.0_1", 
"KHI_ISB_KHI+ISB_PK-308_40.0_0", "ISB_KHI_ISB+KHI_PF-124_20.0_1", 
"ISB_KHI_ISB+KHI_PK-301_40.0_0", "KHI_LHE_KHI+LHE_PA-408_35.0_1", 
"LHE_KHI_LHE+KHI_PF-144_20.0_2", "KHI_ISB_KHI+ISB_PF-121_20.0_2", 
"KHI_ISB_KHI+ISB_PA-204_35.0_1", "ISB_KHI_ISB+KHI_PK-309_40.0_0", 
"ISB_KHI_ISB+KHI_PA-223_20.0_1", "KHI_ISB_KHI+ISB_PA-206_35.0_1", 
"LHE_KHI_LHE+KHI_PF-142_32.0_1", "LHE_KHI_LHE+KHI_PF-142_20.0_1", 
"KHI_ISB_KHI+ISB_PF-123_20.0_2", "ISB_KHI_ISB+KHI_PA-209_15.0_1", 
"KHI_ISB_KHI+ISB_PA-204_35.0_1", "ISB_KHI_ISB+KHI_PA-201_20.0_1", 
"KHI_ISB_KHI+ISB_PK-368_20.0_0", "ISB_KHI_ISB+KHI_PA-205_20.0_1", 
"KHI_ISB_KHI+ISB_PF-121_20.0_1", "ISB_KHI_ISB+KHI_PF-124_20.0_1", 
"ISB_KHI_ISB+KHI_PA-205_15.0_1", "KHI_LHE_KHI+LHE_PF-145_20.0_2", 
"KHI_LHE_KHI+LHE_PA-406_35.0_1", "KHI_ISB_KHI+ISB_PK-308_20.0_0", 
"LHE_KHI_LHE+KHI_PA-401_20.0_1", "LHE_KHI_LHE+KHI_PA-401_15.0_1", 
"KHI_ISB_KHI+ISB_PA-204_35.0_1", "KHI_LHE_KHI+LHE_PA-406_35.0_1", 
"KHI_ISB_KHI+ISB_PA-206_35.0_1", "KHI_ISB_KHI+ISB_PF-121_20.0_1", 
"ISB_KHI_ISB+KHI_PA-205_20.0_1", "LHE_KHI_LHE+KHI_PF-142_20.0_1", 
"LHE_KHI_LHE+KHI_PF-146_20.0_2", "LHE_KHI_LHE+KHI_PA-401_35.0_1", 
"ISB_KHI_ISB+KHI_PA-209_15.0_1", "ISB_KHI_ISB+KHI_PK-301_40.0_0", 
"ISB_KHI_ISB+KHI_PA-205_35.0_1", "KHI_LHE_KHI+LHE_PA-406_15.0_1", 
"KHI_ISB_KHI+ISB_PF-123_20.0_1", "ISB_KHI_ISB+KHI_PA-201_35.0_1", 
"KHI_ISB_KHI+ISB_PK-300_40.0_0", "KHI_LHE_KHI+LHE_PA-402_35.0_1", 
"ISB_KHI_ISB+KHI_ER-505_20.0_1", "ISB_KHI_ISB+KHI_PF-122_20.0_2", 
"ISB_KHI_ISB+KHI_PA-207_15.0_1", "KHI_LHE_KHI+LHE_PA-404_35.0_1", 
"KHI_ISB_KHI+ISB_PF-123_20.0_1", "ISB_KHI_ISB+KHI_ER-503_20.0_1", 
"ISB_GIL_ISB+GIL_PK-605_20.0_0", "KHI_ISB_KHI+ISB_PF-123_20.0_1", 
"KHI_ISB_KHI+ISB_PA-200_15.0_1", "ISB_KHI_ISB+KHI_PF-122_20.0_2", 
"KHI_LHE_KHI+LHE_PA-404_35.0_1", "ISB_KHI_ISB+KHI_PF-122_20.0_2", 
"PEW_KHI_PEW+KHI_PF-152_20.0_1", "LHE_KHI_LHE+KHI_PK-303_20.0_0", 
"KHI_ISB_KHI+ISB_PA-222_35.0_1", "ISB_KHI_ISB+KHI_PF-124_20.0_1"
), created_date = c("2021-04-20", "2021-05-27", "2021-02-13", 
"2021-08-14", "2021-08-11", "2021-08-21", "2021-01-26", "2021-08-21", 
"2021-05-24", "2021-09-15", "2021-06-05", "2021-07-19", "2021-09-29", 
"2021-07-02", "2021-08-10", "2021-01-04", "2021-07-15", "2021-07-14", 
"2021-08-13", "2021-01-11", "2021-09-13", "2021-09-20", "2021-05-27", 
"2021-02-20", "2021-08-15", "2021-07-27", "2021-08-26", "2021-09-15", 
"2021-08-02", "2021-06-25", "2021-05-15", "2021-08-26", "2021-07-30",
"2021-06-27", "2021-08-07", "2021-03-19", "2021-03-02", "2021-06-06", 
"2021-08-15", "2021-06-27", "2021-09-19", "2021-07-28", "2021-08-09", 
"2021-08-16", "2021-09-09", "2021-06-04", "2021-08-12", "2021-05-15", 
"2021-07-26", "2021-05-27", "2021-08-12", "2021-08-02", "2021-01-26", 
"2021-04-20", "2021-08-26", "2021-08-26", "2021-03-21", "2021-01-09", 
"2021-04-23", "2021-01-04", "2021-08-13", "2021-06-22", "2021-05-31", 
"2021-08-18", "2021-06-16", "2021-08-14", "2021-08-10", "2021-06-16", 
"2021-04-08", "2021-05-20", "2021-06-22", "2021-04-20", "2021-01-05", 
"2021-02-27", "2021-07-07", "2021-03-26", "2021-08-16", "2021-05-01", 
"2021-07-31", "2021-06-14", "2021-06-16", "2021-03-25", "2021-09-14", 
"2021-06-06", "2021-09-02", "2021-08-06", "2021-07-18", "2021-02-28", 
"2021-04-28", "2021-09-19", "2021-08-25", "2021-06-17", "2021-06-07", 
"2021-06-17", "2021-07-07", "2021-08-23", "2021-07-09", "2021-07-19", 
"2021-07-14", "2021-05-21"), gross_fare = c(7796, 7427, 11504, 
6870, 6580, 14945, 8697, 7524, 7124, 6785, 11858, 7524, 11500, 
9525, 6785, 8739, 8200, 13560, 9045, 7400, 7524, 12500, 7458, 
14000, 6570, 9525, 6220, 10545, 8310, 7900, 7820, 8410, 11285, 
19892, 6810, 9800, 11441, 11900, 6570, 13592, 11500, 8300, 20380, 
8525, 7340, 9707, 7870, 10655, 10545, 11798, 14645, 10545, 8650, 
8650, 7870, 12945, 10799, 10227, 6765, 10227, 20120, 11045, 9403, 
7870, 7124, 6570, 6810, 6531, 8605, 7124, 11072, 7390, 10227, 
13435, 10530, 12280, 18945, 11147, 10545, 6531, 6620, 10799, 
18480, 32702, 5606, 13560, 23895, 8027, 9655, 11500, 11990, 6620, 
9403, 7620, 14645, 19105, 9000, 6440, 12645, 8025)), row.names = c(NA, 
-100L), class = c("data.table", "data.frame")))
```

Comment: flights[, ':='(max_day = max(gross_fare),min_day=min(gross_fare),diff= max(gross_fare)-min(gross_fare)), by = c("key", "created_date")]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I guess this line of code should do the job:

```r
library(data.table)

flights[,  .(min_day = min(gross_fare), max_day = max(gross_fare), diff = max(gross_fare) - min(gross_fare)), by = .(key, created_date)][]
```

Comment: This line of code very well did do the job, if you don't mind explaining though, can you tell me what ```.( )``` means and what the [ ] at the end does

Comment: Hi @MSasta. Glad that I could help you. The `.( )` part is just an alias for `list( )` (you can use `list( )` instead if you prefer). The `[ ]` at the end returns/displays the frame of the resulting `data.table`. If you remove this part (you can try and see), R will do the job but you won't see the result.

Answer (score 0):

Since the function `findr` returns a list, there's no need to complicate things:

```
findr <- function(x) {list(max = max(x), min = min(x))}

flights[, c("max_day", "min_day") := findr(gross_fare), by = list(key, created_date)][]
```

To also return the difference between `max` and `min`, use

```
findr2 <- function(x) {
  list(max = max(x), min = min(x), diff = diff(range(x)))
}

flights[, c("max_day", "min_day", "diff_day") := findr2(gross_fare), by = list(key, created_date)][]
```

Comment: I'd think the summarization would return fewer rows than the original data; your second block does not. BTW: if `findr2`'s variable names are good enough, one could do `flights[, findr2(gross_fare), by=...]` without assignment, and it still "just works", per your first point.